teleop_twist_keyboard / any teleop
More so a general question, when working with teleop_twist_keyboard node how does it interpret how I move my robot? If I was looking to design a robot similar to Boston Dynamic's Spot then there is a lot more that goes into moving forward then just rotation of a motor, so how does this work?
Any info would help, thanks.

I am answering this in the format that will hopefully help you understand how to find this type of answer on your own in the future. The first step is to find what the tool outputs. In this case:

"This node takes keypresses from the keyboard and publishes them as Twist
messages." from https://index.ros.org/r/teleop_twist_keyboard/

Also from that same link from context you can find that it publishes to the /cmd_vel topic.
From there you can look up the message type: https://docs.ros.org/en/latest/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html
So now we know that that tool publishes a twist message to /cmd_vel.
Another way to get to this same information would be to run the tool and then call ros2 node info /teleop_twist_keyboard which would show you the publishers and the message types (among other things).
  Publishers:
    /cmd_vel: geometry_msgs/msg/Twist

From there it would be your responsibility as the robot developer to have your robot subscribe to the /cmd_vel topic and obey the twist command as it makes sense for that particular robot. For a wheeled robot it may see the command to go forward and set equal power to all motors while a walking robot make see the command to go forward and activate a walking sequence. I would suggest that you play around with echoing that /cmd_vel topic while running the teleop_twist_keyboard in order to get more familiar and more comfortable with how that works. THat helps you see the xyz components of the linear and angular components in the twist message that get set when you indicate different directions of motion.

Just to clarify, if my node is subscribed to the /cmd_vel topic, I will be receiving linear and angular movement commands. Then I need to program how to interpret these commands?

Yes, you've got it.
